# Read files from directory and save to array of object

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, readline

I have a directory of the tax file of employees. Each file has a filename as employee code. I am reading each file and extract some components and save to an array of employee objects.

```
const readline = require('readline');
let empArr = [];

function readFiles(dirname) {
fs.readdir(dirname, async function (err,filenames) {

if(err) {
  return err;
}

for await (file of filenames) {
  const filePath = path.join(__dirname,directoryPath,file);
  const readStream =  fs.createReadStream(filePath);   
  const fileContent = readline.createInterface({
    input: readStream
  });    
 
  let employeeObj = {
    empId : '',
    TotalEarning:'',
    ProfessionalTax:0,
    GrossIncome:0,
    isDone:false
  };

  fileContent.on('line', function(line) {         
    if(!employeeObj.empId &&  line.includes("Employee:")) {    
      const empId = line.replace('Employee: ','').split(" ")[0];    
      employeeObj.empId = empId;
    }
    else if(line.includes('Total Earnings')) {
      const amount = line.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,'');      
      employeeObj.TotalEarning = amount;
    } 
    else if(line.includes('Profession Tax')) {        
      const amount = line.split(" ").pop() || 0;    
      employeeObj.ProfessionalTax = amount;
    } 
    else if(line.includes('Gross Income')) {
      const amount = line.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,'');      
      employeeObj.GrossIncome = amount ||0;
    } 
    else if(line.includes('finance department immediately')) {
      employeeObj.isDone =true;
      empArr.push(employeeObj);           
    }
  });

  fileContent.on('close', function() {
    fileContent.close();      
  });
  }    
 })
}

readFiles(directoryPath);
```

I am not able to get empArr. After getting the array, I need to save to excel. That part I will try after getting the array of employee objects.

Comment: what is an issue? You are unable to readline as per the conditions you have added? Or Is there any other errors? The file that is being read, what is the extension? Are you getting proper data? Have you checked what is coming including filepath, filename, etc?

Comment: One piece of news is that the `await` in `for await (file of filenames)` doesn't do anything.  `await` only does something useful when awaiting a promise.

Comment: So, the main issue here is that you're kicking off a bunch of asynchronous operations inside a `for` loop and they all run in parallel and you have no way of knowing when they are all done.  So, you have no way of knowing when `empArr` is fully populated and thus no way to use it.  The interface to the readline module you're using is entirely non-blocking and asynchronous.  So you run your `for` loop which sets up a bunch of `readline` objects, then your `for` loop finishes and then all the `readline` start firing their `line` events.  Meanwhile, your function has already returned.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara The file is being read and employeeObj is also right. Just the issue is it gets added to empArr and after that I am not sure where to return the empArr

Comment: @jfriend00 yes empArr is full when the there is no file left to be processed. When i try console.log(empArr) outside the for() loop , I get empty array.

Comment: @DevendraSingh - Of course, because outside the `for` loop, none of the processing is done yet.  You're examining the variable BEFORE it has been populated.  You need more understanding of what "non-blocking, asynchronous" means in nodejs and how that affects the timing of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working after reading several articles on closure and promises. The below code works for me and sends me array of employees that are processed.

```
const directoryPath = './tax/';

function readFiles(dirname) {
  fs.readdir(dirname, async function (err,filenames) {    
   if(err) {
     return err;
   }

  let promiseArr = filenames.map( file=> {
    return new Promise((resolve)=>{
      processFile(file, resolve)
    })
 });

 Promise.all(promiseArr).then((ret)=>console.log(ret));   
 })
}
 

function processFile(file, callback) {
     const filePath = path.join(__dirname,directoryPath,file);
     const readStream =  fs.createReadStream(filePath);   
     const fileContent = readline.createInterface({
      input: readStream
     });    
  
    let employeeObj = {
      empId : '',
      TotalEarning:'',
      ProfessionalTax:0,
      GrossIncome:0,
      isDone:false
    };

   fileContent.on('line', function(line) {         
    if(!employeeObj.empId &&  line.includes("Employee:")) {    
      const empId = line.replace('Employee: ','').split(" ")[0];    
      employeeObj.empId = empId;
    }
    else if(line.includes('Total Earnings')) {
      const amount = line.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,'');      
      employeeObj.TotalEarning = amount;
    } 
    else if(line.includes('Profession Tax')) {        
      const amount = line.split(" ").pop() || 0;    
      employeeObj.ProfessionalTax = amount;
    } 
    else if(line.includes('Gross Income')) {
      const amount = line.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,'');      
      employeeObj.GrossIncome = amount ||0;
    } 
    else if(line.includes('finance department immediately')) {
      employeeObj.isDone = true;   
      return callback(employeeObj);
    }
    
  });

  fileContent.on('close', function() {
    fileContent.close();      
  }); 
}

readFiles(directoryPath);
```

Surely, the code can be improved further.